Movie involving virtual reality, a little person with a girlfriend or wife, and sex/nudity
To be honest, I just remember watching this movie and for like two months it's bugging me that I don't know the name, but here are the details I can remember.
It's a movie that has the element of going into the digital world. I don't remember the what the movie's about but I know that these people can go into the digital world and there are like avatars, if I remember, like mannequins.
I can describe two people in the movie and it's the "couple." There is this black midget dude (which I think is a condition, because he has a cane, if I remember) and he has a girlfriend or wife, I don’t remember. In like the first scene, he visits her in a gym where she practices boxing and later he watches her in the shower (this movie shows nudity). She invites him into the shower but he doesn't get naked, he just starts like licking or touching her thigh, I don't know.
The other scene I remember from the movie involves the same couple, but this scene has the black midget dude in the virtual world like trapped, I think, and he's watching the outside world from the virtual world and sees his girlfriend having sex with another dude, pretty much.
That's all I have regarding this. I think it's an old movie. I watched it on a bootleg website for free movies and I can't get it out of my head and I need to know the name.

Was this porn? It sounds like porn.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

@Valorum: Does it matter if the movie has pornographic elements? If this is an issue, it would exclude important science fiction movies like Poor Things and Barbarella.

@KlausÆ.Mogensen Possibly there's a difference between sci-fi movies with explicit content, and porn movies with a (quasi) sci-fi setting ("Hi, I'm the intergalactic plumber...").

@KlausÆ.Mogensen - Nah. We don't care if it's porn (per se) but it would make it a different kind of ID question

Whether it's porn or not also let's people know which cabinet to look in! :)
